# O que é um algoritmo?

Tags: algoritmo

Eu gostaria de saber o que são algoritmos. Eu programo em C, estudo C++ e Python. Em todos os cursos online que fiz, ouvi falar de um tal algoritmo, mas não sei o que é.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Um algoritmo nada mais é do que uma receita (como script de filme, receita de bolo) que mostra passo a passo os procedimentos necessários para a resolução de uma tarefa. Ele não responde a pergunta **o que fazer**?, mas sim **como fazer**. É uma sequência lógica, finita e definida de instruções que devem ser seguidas para resolver um problema ou executar uma tarefa.

> **Trocando em miúdos**

O que você faz em C, C++ e Python (Linguagens que você sabe) e em qualquer outra linguagem é implementar um algoritmo, mesmo quando é somente um `hello world`, um `for` que imprime de `0` a `10`.

Exemplo de algoritmo para troca de uma lâmpada:

```
 Início
   Verifica se o interruptor está desligado;
   Procura uma lâmpada nova;
   Pega uma escada;
   Leva a escada até o local;
   Posiciona a escada;
   Sobe os degraus;
   Para na altura apropriada;
   Retira a lâmpada queimada;
   Coloca a lâmpada nova;
   Desce da escada;
   Aciona o interruptor;
     Se a lâmpada não acender, então:
         Retira a lâmpada queimada;
         Coloca outra lâmpada nova
     Senão
         Tarefa terminada;
   Joga a lâmpada queimada no lixo; 
  Guarda a escada;
 Fim
```

Fluxograma de um algoritmo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Classificações de Algoritmos por implementações:**

**Recursivo ou iterativo** - um algoritmo recursivo possui a característica de invocar a si mesmo repetidamente até que certa condição seja satisfeita e ele é terminado.

**Lógico** - um algoritmo pode ser visto como uma dedução lógica controlada.

**Serial ou paralelo** - algoritmos são geralmente assumidos por serem executados instrução a instrução individualmente, como uma lista de execução, o que constitui um algoritmo serial.

**Determinístico ou não-determinístico** - algoritmos determinísticos resolvem o problema com uma decisão exata a cada passo enquanto algoritmos não-determinísticos resolvem o problema ao deduzir os melhores passos através de estimativas sob forma de heurísticas.

**Exato ou aproximado** - enquanto alguns algoritmos encontram uma resposta exata, algoritmos de aproximação procuram uma resposta próxima a verdadeira solução, seja através de estratégia determinística ou aleatória.

> **Classificação de Algoritmos por paradigma:**

**Divisão e conquista** - algoritmos de divisão e conquista reduzem repetidamente o problema em sub-problemas, geralmente de forma recursiva, até que o sub-problema é pequeno o suficiente para ser resolvido.

**Programação dinâmica** - pode-se utilizar a programação dinâmica para evitar o re-cálculo de solução já resolvidas anteriormente.

**Algoritmo ganancioso** - um algoritmo ganancioso é similar à programação dinâmica, mas difere na medida em que as soluções dos sub-problemas não precisam ser conhecidas a cada passo, uma escolha gananciosa pode ser feita a cada momento com o que até então parece ser mais adequado.

**Programação linear** - A resolução de um problema através de programação linear envolve a maximização / minimização das entradas de um conjunto de desigualdades lineares.

**Redução** - a redução resolve o problema ao transformá-lo em outro problema. É chamado também transformação e conquista.

**Busca e enumeração** - vários problemas podem ser modelados através de grafos. Um algoritmo de exploração de grafo pode ser usado para caminhar pela estrutura e retornam informações úteis para a resolução do problema.

**Paradigma heurístico e probabilístico** - algoritmos probabilísticos realizam escolhas aleatoriamente. Algoritmos genéticos tentam encontrar a solução através de ciclos de mutações evolucionárias entre gerações de passos, tendendo para a solução exata do problema.

Fontes:

[O que é um algoritmo - Tecmundo](http://www.tecmundo.com.br/programacao/2082-o-que-e-algoritmo-.htm)

[Algoritmo - Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo)

Comment: Ficou enorme. Mas gostei. Deixe eu ver se entendi: o algoritmo é o que mostra os passos para a resolução de uma tarefa. Por exemplo, ao criar um laço while para contar de 1 a 10, eu fiz um algoritmo que mostra todos os passos para fazer o programa ir até o 10 e parar.

Comment: você implementou um algoritmo que imprime de 0 a 10 e finaliza.

Comment: Você conhece portugol? ela é uma linguagem pseudo-linguagem usada para ensinar estruturação de algoritmos.

Comment: Da mesma maneira para o Hello World, né?

Comment: Sim. Já ouvi falar de Portugol. Eu vi sobre isso na Wikipedia.

Comment: Uma opinião minha: É melhor aprender a criar algoritmos direto na linguagem `C` por que você aprende a criar algoritmos e ao mesmo tempo uma linguagem de programação de verdade.

Answer (score 2):

É uma sequência finita de regras, raciocínios ou operações que, aplicada a um número finito de dados, permite solucionar classes semelhantes de problemas. Praticamente resumindo é como uma receita de bolo, terá que realizar passo a passo para resolver um problema. Geralmente no inicio dos estudos em computação o pessoal opta por estudar algoritmos com a linguagem Portugol no VisualG. (Pois a sintaxe é em português e aparenta ser mais fácil)